# Help with Nonlinear Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Hello guys :) I've got a bit of an issue with the following recurrence relation:

Let $\omega _1 = 1$. Now, let $\omega _n$ be defined as follows
$$
w_n = 1 + \sum _{k=1}^{n-1}C^{k}_{n-k} \, \omega _k \, \omega _{n-k}
$$
where
$$
C^{k}_{n-k} = \frac{1+\delta^{k}_{n-k}}{2} = \left\lbrace
\begin{array}{l l}
1/2, & n \neq n-k \\
1, & n= n-k 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
My goal was to (at least attempt) to find a closed form for $\omega _n$, but it has proven quite difficult for me. I've tried rewriting the term $C^{k}_{n-k} \, \omega _k \, \omega _{n-k}$ as the application of a bilinear form, approximating the sum as a weighted convolution by setting $\omega _0 = 0$ artificially, and some other things but it just won't budge. To be honest, my repertoire of recurrence tricks isn't too vast, and I've read online that only a few classes of nonlinear recurrence relations actually have a closed form. Any help and kind observations would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the first few terms and using the gfun package in Maple, it appears that the generating function of your sequence is

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \omega_n x^n  = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{1-3x}{1-x}} $$

Comment: I don't have that software, could you confirm the following values hold? $\omega _7 = 96$, $\omega _{15} = 440915$.

Comment: No, I get $\omega_7 = 753/16$ and $\omega_{15} = 184704489/2048$.  Are you sure you wrote the recurrence correctly?

Comment: Then it doesn't work :( Direct computation shows those values are correct, and I've confirmed them by hand.

Comment: What are your values for $\omega_2$ to $\omega_6$?

Comment: $\omega _2 = 1 + \omega_1 \omega _1 = 2$, $\omega_6 = 41$. (I noticed a typo in the definition on $C^k _{n-k}$! Sorry about that :( )

Comment: Ah, maybe you meant $C^k_{n-k} = 1$ if $n = 2k$, not $n=k$ or $n=n-k$ (which can't happen if $k$ goes from $1$ to $n-1$).

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A300443](https://oeis.org/A300443).

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll have a look. Seems like there's no closed form though.